# QML ListView populate opacity animation

Tags: qt, listview, animation, qml

I have a `ListView` and I want to create an fade-in effect for `populate` ViewTransition. But it not works as expected. It seems that initial opacity of the delegate is 1.0 and so I need to set `from` property of the animation.
But it looked like a flashing. So I need to set initial opacity value of my delegate to `0.0`.
Now I have a new problem... when I flick the list, delegates default opacity is `0.0` and so they are invisible.
So my question: Can anybody create a perfect fade-in animation for `populate` property of the ListView?

Thank you

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    id: root
    property alias model: list.model
    ListView {
        id: list
        width: 300; height: 500
        model: sampleModel
        spacing: 30
        footer: Item { width: 1; height: 30 }
        populate: Transition {
            id: _popuTrans
            SequentialAnimation {
                PauseAnimation {
                    duration: 100*_popuTrans.ViewTransition.index
                }
                NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0.0; to: 1.0; duration: 200 }
                PropertyAction { property: "opacity"; value: 1.0 }
            }
        }

        delegate: Component {
            Column {

                width: parent.width
                spacing: 13
                opacity: 0.0
                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width*0.84
                    height: 1
                    color: colorPalette.altBackgroundColor
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
                Row {
                    width: parent.width
                    spacing: width*0.07
                    Text {
                        id: valueTxt
                        font { pointSize: 13 }
                        color: "black"
                        width: parent.width*0.64
                        text: model.body
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                    }
                    Text {
                        id: keyTxt
                        font { pointSize: 15; weight: Font.Medium }
                        color: "black"
                        width: parent.width*0.29
                        text: model.title
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: sampleModel
        ListElement {
            title: "ابعاد"
            body: "عرض: 123mm\nطول: 650mm\nارتفاع: 17mm"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "وزن"
            body: "1.3kg"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "پردازنده"
            body: "Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 3.1GHz"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "سیستم عامل"
            body: "Microsoft Windows 10 Starter"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "رنگ‌ها"
            body: "قرمز، نوک مدادی، سفید"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "اتصالات"
            body: "2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A\n1 x Audio jack: headphone / mic-in\n1 x Combo Nano SIM (tray with needle)\n1 x MicroSD card reader slot (supports up to 256GB)\n1 x HDMI\n1 x DC in"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "باتری"
            body: "Li-ion 8345mAh Turbo Charge Capable"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "حافظه RAM"
            body: "DDR4 2x8GB AData"
        }


        ListElement {
            title: "ابعاد"
            body: "عرض: 123mm\nطول: 650mm\nارتفاع: 17mm"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "وزن"
            body: "1.3kg"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "پردازنده"
            body: "Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 3.1GHz"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "سیستم عامل"
            body: "Microsoft Windows 10 Starter"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "رنگ‌ها"
            body: "قرمز، نوک مدادی، سفید"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "اتصالات"
            body: "2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A\n1 x Audio jack: headphone / mic-in\n1 x Combo Nano SIM (tray with needle)\n1 x MicroSD card reader slot (supports up to 256GB)\n1 x HDMI\n1 x DC in"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "باتری"
            body: "Li-ion 8345mAh Turbo Charge Capable"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "حافظه RAM"
            body: "DDR4 2x8GB AData"
        }ListElement {
            title: "ابعاد"
            body: "عرض: 123mm\nطول: 650mm\nارتفاع: 17mm"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "وزن"
            body: "1.3kg"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "پردازنده"
            body: "Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 3.1GHz"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "سیستم عامل"
            body: "Microsoft Windows 10 Starter"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "رنگ‌ها"
            body: "قرمز، نوک مدادی، سفید"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "اتصالات"
            body: "2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A\n1 x Audio jack: headphone / mic-in\n1 x Combo Nano SIM (tray with needle)\n1 x MicroSD card reader slot (supports up to 256GB)\n1 x HDMI\n1 x DC in"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "باتری"
            body: "Li-ion 8345mAh Turbo Charge Capable"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "حافظه RAM"
            body: "DDR4 2x8GB AData"
        }ListElement {
            title: "ابعاد"
            body: "عرض: 123mm\nطول: 650mm\nارتفاع: 17mm"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "وزن"
            body: "1.3kg"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "پردازنده"
            body: "Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 3.1GHz"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "سیستم عامل"
            body: "Microsoft Windows 10 Starter"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "رنگ‌ها"
            body: "قرمز، نوک مدادی، سفید"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "اتصالات"
            body: "2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A\n1 x Audio jack: headphone / mic-in\n1 x Combo Nano SIM (tray with needle)\n1 x MicroSD card reader slot (supports up to 256GB)\n1 x HDMI\n1 x DC in"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "باتری"
            body: "Li-ion 8345mAh Turbo Charge Capable"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "حافظه RAM"
            body: "DDR4 2x8GB AData"
        }ListElement {
            title: "ابعاد"
            body: "عرض: 123mm\nطول: 650mm\nارتفاع: 17mm"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "وزن"
            body: "1.3kg"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "پردازنده"
            body: "Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 3.1GHz"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "سیستم عامل"
            body: "Microsoft Windows 10 Starter"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "رنگ‌ها"
            body: "قرمز، نوک مدادی، سفید"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "اتصالات"
            body: "2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-A\n1 x Audio jack: headphone / mic-in\n1 x Combo Nano SIM (tray with needle)\n1 x MicroSD card reader slot (supports up to 256GB)\n1 x HDMI\n1 x DC in"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "باتری"
            body: "Li-ion 8345mAh Turbo Charge Capable"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "حافظه RAM"
            body: "DDR4 2x8GB AData"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flashing is due to your `PauseAnimation`, the opacity stays at 1 during its entire duration. Here is a beautiful graph illustrating the delegate's opacity over time during the `populate` transition :

[image: opacity over time during the populate transition]

You need to set the opacity of the delegates to 0 before the `PauseAnimation`, and in the `populate` transition, not directly in the delegate (the transition is only applied to visible delegates, that's why delegates below the content area stay invisible).

In order to do this, remove the `opacity: 0` in your delegate and just add a `PropertyAction` before the `PauseAnimation` in your transition:

```
populate: Transition {
    id: _popuTrans
    SequentialAnimation {
        PropertyAction { property: "opacity"; value: 0.0 }
        PauseAnimation { duration: 100*_popuTrans.ViewTransition.index }
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0.0; to: 1.0; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought so, too. But that is not the only issue. There seems to be some problem with the `populate`-transition. As soon as anything is assigned to it, it messes up the instantiation.

Comment: @derM This seems to work fine here, what's the problem?

Comment: If I have a simple `ListView { model: 100; anchors.fill:parent; spacing: 3; delegate: Rectangle { width:100; height: 20; color: "red" }}` I get some lets say 20 Rectangles drawn on my screen. As soon as I set any Transition to `populate` this breaks - I get just a hand full like 1 or 7 or 8 drawn... My guesses are, that it has something to do with `ListView`s ignoring fully transparent elements on layout. It might have something to do with the changing size of the `ListView` when *filling* an `ApplicationWindow`. I will investigate it.